# Query Google Admin Directory users for partial name match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm trying to do two things:

- Query `AdminDirectory.Users.list` by `name` field to return a list of anyone whose name matches a given string (even partially)
- If possible, prevent the email address field from being included in the search

For example, "donald" should return data for the users Donald Duck, Donald Trump, and Ronald McDonald. If someone searched for "onald", that should work too.

The below sort of works. In the "donald" scenario, it would return only Donald Duck's data. For some reason it won't return more than one user.

```
function processForm(formObject) { // formObject comes from form on front end
    var textSearchObject = formObject.textSearch; // "donald"

    var userList = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
        domain: 'somedomain.com',
        query: "name:'" + textSearchObject + "'",
        viewType: 'domain_public',
        projection: 'full'
    }).users;

    return userList;
}
```

I know, `query: "name:'" + textSearchObject + "'"` looks very strange and most people would just use `query: textSearchObject`. The problem is that this searches email addresses - I need to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I believe you may need to put wildcards on either side of textSearchObject such as: `query: "name:'*" + textSearchObject + "*'",`

Comment: The asterix breaks the code...

Comment: @PeterHerrmann, you're right! It's right there in the link you provided, very easy to miss in the documentation:
`The field starts with the value. For example, a query with givenName:Jane* matches users with givenName values of "Jane", "Jane Ann", and "Janet" but not "Sarah Jane".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're limited to "starts with" searching e.g. `Donald*` but you can search just the `givenName`, `familyName` or the combined name (`fullName`). Full documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users